# Connect Wireless router via Ubuntu command line

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I would like to connect to my TP_Link Wireless router via command line (from an Ubuntu Server). I'm trying with this:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 essid {MY ESSID}
iwconfig wlan0 key s:{PASSWORD}
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

At this point, my iwconfig wlan0 output looks good, then I request an IP from the AP's DHCP server:

```
dhclient -r
dhclient wlan0
```

This last command hangs for 2-3 minutes, then exits without any output. The iwconfig wlan0 output the same, still "Access Point: Not-Associated"
Looks like I cannot get an IP.

Can anybody help what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry `iwconfig` only works for WEP encryption.

please use the **wpa_supplicant**

---

edit the `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` file using gedit or vim or what ever you prefer.

append to the end of the file

```
network={
    ssid="my network"
    scan_ssid=1 //this must be added if the AP doesnt broadcast its ssid
    psk="sekret"
}
```

then you can manually turn on the supplicant

```
# wpa_supplicant -B -i interface -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

once connected you can obtain an address via dhcp with

```
# dhcpd interface
```

Comment: Man, you're a lifesaver. Thanks, wpa_supplicant works like a charm

Comment: your very welcome. :-)